# Set property (date) of images in Imagecollection from value in date band in Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, datetime

I have a Imagecollection with 2 bands per image. One is the 'date' band. The pixel values from this band are equal in every image. The value of one of the pixels i want to use to add as date to the properties of the image. In order to use `filter.Date()`. i dont understand the error because '20141018' is a string and 'yMd' is the right format to transform or isn't it? http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

```
var new_collection = vvAscending
    .map(function(image) {
      return ee.Feature(null, {'date': ee.Date.parse('yMd',image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(),geometry,10).get('date'))})
    })
    .distinct('date')
    .aggregate_array('date')
print("new_collection ",new_collection )
```

The Error i get is:

```
ComputedObject (Error)
Collection.reduceColumns: Error in map(ID=0):
Date.parse: Date/time '20141018' cannot be parsed with format 'yMd'.
```

Line 107:113
https://code.earthengine.google.com/6afaa18508be5b108581056077efe6ea

Comment: Correct format should be `yyyyMMdd`.

Comment: Ouh man so simple ;) it works!